# How to create New Column containing Calculated Values with Conditional Statements in play

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, if-statement

Context:

1. I have a dataframe on football match statistics
2. This dataframe is missing info on outcome of the match
3. Hence, I am trying to create a column that lets me know if the match outcome is a "Win" or "Lose"
4. The dataframe contains goals scored by Home & Away teams
5. I am trying to populate a new column with "Win" when Home goals is more than Away goals
6. You can see in my code below that the new column I was trying to create is called "outcome"

---

Below's working code should give a sense of what I am trying to do, and am doing wrong...

```
for index, row in match_df.iterrows():
    if match_df.home_team_goal > match_df.away_team_goal:
        match_df.loc[index, "outcome"] = "Win"
    else:
        match_df.loc[index, "outcome"] = "Lose"
```

---

Error Message:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below as well:

```
match_df['outcome'] = 'Win'
match_df.loc[match_df.home_team_goal < match_df.away_team_goal, 'outcome'] = 'Lose'
```

And now:

```
print(match_df)
```

Would be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should try not using for loop when you with `pandas`: `np.where`

```
import pandas as pd; import numpy as np

match_df['outcome']=np.where(match_df.home_team_goal > match_df.away_team_goal,'win','lose')
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps, something new for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

To edit your try:

```
for index, row in match_df.iterrows():
    if row['home_team_goal'] > row['away_team_goal']:
        match_df.loc[index, "outcome"] = "Win"
    else:
        match_df.loc[index, "outcome"] = "Lose"
```

Or use below code for fast results:

```
df.outcome.fillna(np.where(df.home_team_goal > df.away_team_goal, "Win", "Lose") )
```